# Drop down list inside iframe

Tags: iframe

I just figure it out that if I put my drop down menu inside `iframe`, all my menus from it will be covered by `iframe`. The problem is - I dunno how long menu is gonna be, so I can't set the height, and actually I don't want to make it really long. Question: is it possible that drop down menus kinda come out from `iframe` and appear on parent window?
for example:

> ```
> <ul id="myMenu">
> <li><a href="#" onmouseover="mopen('m1')">Home</a>
>     <div id="m1" onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()">
>     <a href="#">link1</a>
>     <a href="#">link2</a>
>     <a href="#">link3</a>
>     </div>
> </li> 
> </ul>
> ```

this my menu inside `iframe` file, I want to display `div Home` in parent window when you rollover the `Home` link. thank you everyone in-advance. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Just don't use the `<iframe>`

Comment: **SLaks** did you see the question? I am not asking what should I use. If I am asking about `iframe` there is suppose to be a reason for that.

Comment: Yes.  The answer is to not use an `<iframe>`.  Your life will be infinitely easier without `<iframe>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to set the parent frame's `<iframe>` element's `style.height` to an appropriate value.

Comment: that's the option! It is have to be an embedded code with my menu, and I don't want to make this code too long and if user decided to change something in menu they don't need to change the code. But I am agree its impossible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not possible. However, you can achieve what you wanna do by converting your main page to iframes and leaving the menu in the main page.